# Can someone explain the control flow of modules in System Verilog

Tags: system-verilog, quartus

I know how to link modules but could someone explain the flow of calling the modules to be used when I want it to be used.
Like have a state machine and depending on the state I can call a module to activate, or like if I need to repeat a process how to go back to a module earlier in a state machine.

again I get the instantiating part like this

```
  wire clk;
  wire sig;
  wire out;

  A a(clk, sig, topout);
 B b(clk, sig);
endmodule
```

but can someone explain how to call modules and how the control flow works in general for them?
(I am new to HDLs so I appreciate any help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verilog is a language specifically developed to simulate behavior of hardware. Hardware is a set of transistors and other elements which always statically presented and function in parallel. Functioning of such elements could be enabled or disabled, but the hardware is still present.

Verilog is similar to the hardware in the sense that all its elements are always present, intended for parallel functioning.

The basic functional elements of Verilog are gates, primitives and procedural blocks (i.e., always blocks). Those blocks are connected by wires.

All those elements are then grouped in modules. Modules are used to create logical partitioning of the hardware mode. They cannot be 'called'. They can be instantiated in a hierarchical manner to describe a logical structure of the model. They cannot be instantiated conditionally since they represent pieces of hardware. Different module instances are connected via wires to express hierarchical connectivity between lower-level elements.

There is one exception however, the contents of an always block is pure software. It describes an algorithmic behavior of it and as such, software flow constructs are allowed inside *always* block (specific considerations must be used to make it synthesizable).

As it comes to simulation, Verilog implements an event-driven simulation mode which is intended to mimic parallel execution of hardware. In other words, a Verilog low level primitive (gate or always block) is executed only if at least one of its inputs changes.

The only flow control which is usually used in such models is a sequence of input events and clocks. The latter are used to synchronize results of multiple parallel operations and to organize pipes or other sequential functions.

As I mentioned before, hardware elements can be enabled/disabled by different methods, so the only further control you can use by implementing such methods in your hardware description. For example, all hardware inside a particular module can be turned off by disabling clock signal which the module uses. There could be specific enable/disable signals on wires or in registers, and so on.

Now to your question: your code defines hierarchical instantiation of a couple of modules.

```
module top(out);
 output wire out;

 wire clk;
 wire sig;

 A a(clk, sig, out);
 B b(clk, sig);
endmodule
```

Module 'top' (missing in your example) contains instances of two other modules, A and B.  A and B are module definitions. They are instantiated as corresponding instances 'a' and 'b'. The instances are connected by signals 'clk', which is probably a clock signal, some signal 'sig' which is probably an output of one of the modules and input in another. 'out' is output of module top, which is probably connected to another module or an element in a higher level of hierarchy, not shown here.

The flow control in some sense is defined by the input/output relation between modules 'A' and 'B'. For example:

```
module A(input clk, input sig, output out);
  assign out = sig;
  ...
endmodule

module B(input clk, output sig);
  always@(posedge clk) sig <= some-new-value;
  ...
endmodule
```

However, in general it is defined by the input/output relation of the internal elements inside module (always blocks in the above example). input/output at the module port level is mostly used for semantic checking.

In the event-driven simulation it does not matter hardware of which module is executed first. However as soon as the value of the 'sig' changes in `always@(posedge clk)` of module 'B', simulation will cause hardware in module 'A' (the `assign` statement to be evaluated (or re-evaluated). This is the only way you can express a sequence in the flow at this level. Same as in hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me you are looking at Verilog with the background of a software programmer. Confident in the idea that a program executes linearly. You think of ordered execution. Line 1 before line 2...

Verilog at its heart wants to execute all the lines *simultaneously*. All the time.

This is a very parallel way to program and until you get it, you will struggle to think the right way about it. It is not how normal software works. (I recall it took me weeks to get my head around it.)

You can prefix blocks of simultaneous execution with conditions, which are saying execute the lines in this block when the condition is true. All the time the condition is true. One class of such conditions is the rising edge of a clock: `always @(posedge clk)`. Using this leads to a block of code that execute once *every time* the `clk` ticks (up).

Modules are not like subroutines. They are more like C macros - they effectively inline blocks of code where you place them. These blocks of code execute all the time any conditions that apply to them are true. Typically you conditionalize the internals of a module on the state of the module arguments (or internal register state). It is the connectivity of the modules through the shared arguments that ensures the logic of a system works together.

Comment: thank you for the perspective. So would it be possible to have a finite state machine of the top module where at certain states it sends a signal to another module, like a clk signal in `always @(posedge clk)`, within a certain module which would cause the statements within it to play, and then have the called module send a signal back to that statemachine of the top module to have it continue ?

Comment: Yes. This would be mediated via the value of the arguments to the module. Module input arguments announce the request is ready, and module output arguments announce the response is ready.